# Possible to reach up to the top of a nested selector by using multiple parent selectors?

Tags: ruby, haml, sass

In SCSS, a single `&' will be replaced by the parent selector. I think it should be possible to do the following:

```
#main {
    .post {
        .date {}
        .entry {

            margin-right: 0.833em;

            .title,
            &&&.callout { font-size: 3em; }
        }
    }
}
```

ideally, the preceding would compile to include the following rules:

```
#main .post .entry .title { font-size: 3em; }
#main .callout { font-size: 3em; }
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: That's actually a really bad practice, even if it were possible, because you imply that .callout is a child of .entry, when you actually want it to be a child of #main. If you're using a block of properties repeatedly, you might consider moving them into a mixin instead.

Comment: If it did work, I'd expect it to actually compile to: #main .post .entry .title, #main.callout { font-size: 3em; } ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible in SCSS. The best you can do is

```
#main {
  .callout { font-size: 3em; }

  .post {
    .entry {
      margin-right: 0.833em;

      .title {
        @extend .callout;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which compiles to

```
#main .callout, #main .post .entry .title {
  font-size: 3em; }
#main .post .entry {
  margin-right: 0.833em; }
```

Comment: Ah, I had never used @extend and completely forgot that it existed. That's not too bad at all. Thanks